# Rotate camera along "eye" direction in rgl

Tags: rgl, rotational-matrices

In `rgl`, you can set up camera direction with [rgl.viewpoint](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgl/docs/viewpoint). It accepts `theta`, `phi`: polar coordinates. They specify the position of the camera looking at the origin. However, there is yet another one degree of freedom: angle of rotation of the camera along "eye" vector. I.e. one can imagine two vectors associated with camera: "eye" vector and "up" vector; `theta` and `phi` allow one to adjust "eye" vector, but I want then to adjust "up" vector after it. Is it possible to do it?

I guess that it can be possible to do it with `userMatrix` parameter («4x4 matrix specifying user point of view»), but I found no information how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ?par3d help topic documents the rendering process in the "Rendering" section.  It's often tricky to accomplish what you're asking for, but in this case it's not too hard:

```
par3d(userMatrix = rotationMatrix(20*pi/180, 0,0,1) 
                   %*% par3d("userMatrix"))
```

will rotate by 20 degrees around the user's z-axis, i.e. line of sight.